# Manipulating the map in JS - [GM] Unable to find map

Tags: plugin-googlemaps

I love the new Google Maps plugin, it seems really promising.

I am really struggling to manipuluate the map in JS in the new Google Maps plugin.

I have a dynamic map that filters fatal and serious injury crashes (by mode of transportation, outcome, and year) and adds KML layers.

I'm successfully loading the map in Twig — Now I am working through manipulating it in JS but can't seem to get past the first step.

> Console: [GM] Unable to find map "mapAlpha"

```
  {% set fatalities = craft.entries.section('crashes').outcome('fatal').all() %}
  {% set injuries = craft.entries.section('crashes').outcome('injury').all() %}

  {% set options = {
    'id' : 'mapAlpha'
  } %}

  {% set map = googleMaps.map([], options)
    .zoom(12)
    %}

  {% do map.markers(fatalities, {
    'icon': '/assets/images/ui/red-dot.png',
    'infoWindowTemplate' : '/modules/info-bubble.twig'
  }) %}
  {% do map.markers(injuries, {
    'icon': '/assets/images/ui/blue-dot.png',
    'infoWindowTemplate' : '/modules/info-bubble.twig'
  }) %}


  {{ map.tag() }}

  <script>
  {% js %}
    var map = googleMaps.getMap('mapAlpha');
    
  {% endjs %}
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance, it sounds like it's just a matter of waiting for everything to finish loading. You are trying to call a map which has not yet been initialized.

Good news! The `tag` method includes a [`callback` option](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/google-maps/dynamic-maps/twig-php-methods/#tag-options) which allows you to specify a JavaScript function to be called *after* the map has finished loading...

```
{{ map.tag({
    'callback': 'moreJavascript'
}) }}

{% js %}
    function moreJavascript() {
        var map = googleMaps.getMap('mapAlpha');
        console.log(map);
    }
{% endjs %}
```

Take a look at this [practical example](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/google-maps/guides/clustering-markers/) of how someone could use the `callback` option to enable marker clustering... I know that you aren't trying to cluster your markers, but the broader execution is the same.

Comment: Pefect — I've successfully added a KML layer, is there an example of toggling a map layer on/off?

Comment: That's a separate question, but the answer might be no. I've added a [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/doublesecretagency/craft-googlemaps/issues/24), so feel free to follow along there for developing information.